# How can I make url rewrite on google cloud app engine?

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, url-rewriting, .net-core, react-router

I deployed my client react app and dot net core API on Google Cloud App Engine same service and same version. This is my first time working with App Engine. Usually, when I deploy on IIS I will have a web config to rewrite the Url to using react routing, but seem like URL rewrite is not working with App Engine. Is there any alternative that I can achieve the same results with IIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to App Engine.  Google Cloud App Engine Flex does not run IIS, so it does not read the contents of web.config.

I found this article about rewriting middleware for ASP.NET core:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x
I believe this middleware will let you rewrite urls as you need, but I don't know for sure without your web.config.

An application that uses rewriting middleware instead of web.config will behave the same on IIS and App Engine.

Answer (score 1):

If you using ASP.NET Core maybe you can try this approach?

Add this class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite;
using System;

namespace APA.Web.Common
{
    public class RedirectToWwwRule : IRule
    {
        public virtual void ApplyRule(RewriteContext context)
        {
            var req = context.HttpContext.Request;
            if (req.Host.Host.Equals("localhost", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                context.Result = RuleResult.ContinueRules;
                return;
            }

            if (req.Host.Value.StartsWith("www.", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                context.Result = RuleResult.ContinueRules;
                return;
            }

            var wwwHost = new HostString($"www.{req.Host.Value}");
            var newUrl = UriHelper.BuildAbsolute(req.Scheme, wwwHost, req.PathBase, req.Path, req.QueryString);
            var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
            response.StatusCode = 301;
            response.Headers[Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.HeaderNames.Location] = newUrl;
            context.Result = RuleResult.EndResponse;
        }
    }
}
```

and then use it in Configure Method in Startup.cs.

Add this code to use it:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite;   



public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
      ...
      ...

    var options = new RewriteOptions();
    options.AddRedirectToHttps();
    options.Rules.Add(new RedirectToWwwRule());
    app.UseRewriter(options);
...
```

I am using this code to redirect all the non-www/HTTP traffic to the www/HTTPS version.